# local notifications iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, notifications, ios5

I have an App that uses local notifications intensively. I need sound and visual alert in the same way like iOS 4.0. There is a way I can programmatically enable the notification working in the same way in iOS 5, without having to ask the user to change Settings> Notifications> MyApp?

Comment: Is iOS 5 under NDA currently, as it is still in Beta release?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing some tests with the latest iOS 5 beta 7. It is illegal to ask questions about this topic? I just want to know if anyone has any knowledge if going to be some way to do what I want.

Comment: Why is this question too localized!? This is a very relevant question. Please reopen.

Comment: This question should not be closed as I've encountered this post Beta and no solution??  My localnotifications seem to be disabled by default when running my builds so guessing the same will happen when I put it on appstore.  Would really like to know how to enable these by default

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no differences in implementation of local notifications between iOS 4 and iOS 5. iOS 5 will display them differently, but triggering them is no different.

Comment: Yes, implementation has not changed. But when you updated (at least in beta version of iOS 5) notifications are disabled by default, you have to go Settings>Notificatios>App to change the way they are launched. And I do not want my users have to do this procedure.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that aspect of the beta usage. Generally, if the notifications are on, when you upgrade, Apple will more than likely retain that setting. So this just boils down to a testing issue. Worst case, pop up an alert if notifications are off letting them know the app will not work as intended.

Comment: too localized ?? I am worrying about the exact same issue, and I bet 1000s of others are!! ... People using my app will end up spamming my email saying local notifications won't work .. and the reason is because it's disable in the iPhone's settings ..